# how to install sqlite in a django project

Tags: python, django, sqlite

i am learning django. It seems when you create a new project, a sqlite3 data base comes with it. In my case, when i look in my project, no data base can be found.

```
  Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       13/08/2016     21:26                .idea
d-----       13/08/2016     21:03                AJJL_project
-a----       13/08/2016     20:34            810 manage.py
```

I think maybe i should install sqlite myself. So, how do i do that and how do i insert it in a django project ?

Answer (score 1):

To create a database and tables in database You must run the following command:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Read more about migrations [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-migrate)

Answer (score 0):

run the following commands

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Could you explain how your answer is different from the previous answer?